# Add Class according to the order of appearance

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, customization

My loop returns five posts and the HTML should look like this..

```
<ul>
    <li class="topfive"> ... </li>
    <li class="topfive"> ... </li>
    <li class="topfive"> ... </li>
    <li class="topfive"> ... </li>
    <li class="topfive"> ... </li>
</ul>
```

And, I need to programmatically add classes to them according to the order of appearance, something like this..

```
<ul>
    <li class="topfive first"> ... </li>
    <li class="topfive second"> ... </li>
    <li class="topfive third"> ... </li>
    <li class="topfive fourth"> ... </li>
    <li class="topfive fifth"> ... </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the code I am using to create the loop:

```
function custom_top_products() {
    $args = array (
                'post_type' => 'products',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'orderby' => 'comment_count',
                'posts_per_page' => 5
            );
        $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

        ?>
        <div id="topproducts" class="ratingbox">
            <h3 class="rbh3">Top 5 Products</h3>
            <div class="topproductcontainer">
        <?php
            if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
                $posts->the_post();
            ?>
                <li class="topfive"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>          
            <?php               
            } else {
                echo '<p class="trc">Sorry, No Popular Products Found</p>';
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
            </div>
        </div>      
        <?php
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an array with your classes and loop through alongside with the main loop:

```
function custom_top_products() {
    $classes = array( 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth' );
    $classes_count = count( $classes );

    $posts = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'products',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'comment_count',
        'posts_per_page' => 5
    ) );

    $i = 0;

    ?><div id="topproducts" class="ratingbox">
        <h3 class="rbh3">Top 5 Products</h3>
        <div class="topproductcontainer"><?php
            if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
                    $posts->the_post();
                    ?><li class="topfive <?php echo $classes[$i++ % $classes_count] ?>">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </li><?php
                }

                wp_reset_postdata();
            } else {
                echo '<p class="trc">Sorry, No Popular Products Found</p>';
            }
            ?></div>
    </div><?php
}
```